# magento - how to style only the pressed/active menu item related to the current page we are in?

Tags: php, css, magento

i want to highlight only the pressed menu item in magento, can it be done?

i have tried to achieve this in many ways but none of them succeeded (i can list some of them  here   if it helps)

thank you

1 tried php get url and compare it to the text written inside the a tag

2 tried built-in methodes/id specific to magento

i have made some progress -i added this code to my template file -2columns-left.phtml

```
    <?php
        $routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
         echo $routeName;
       $body_class = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getBodyClass();
        echo $body_class;
        if(strpos(strtolower($body_class),strtolower($routeName)) !== false){
         $nav_active =  "class = 'nav_active'";
         }
        ?>
```

now i have added  $nav_active to the body tag in the same file ,have tried this but it didnt work

```
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?><?php if(strpos(strtolower($body_class),strtolower($routeName)) !== false):?> echo $nav_active  ;?>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with my alternative solution

it is working at my end

just do it like this

```
 <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'your_category_name') != false ) :?> active<?php endif;?>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: thank you liyakat it helped me to make progress ,can you tell me which file controlls the body tag for all pages ? i guess after that all is left  is to add in the css file -->body.a {background....}

Comment: it is respectively calling as you selected layout for your page. for example 1 page layout contenting \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\1column.phtml and also othere like 2columns-right.phtml,2columns-left.phtml,3columns.phtml just add whatever you want to body tag

Comment: @takethat, will u please accept my answer. so if some one wants to do same thing in future so they can use our thread.

Comment: great thats what i did but nothing happend :(                   <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().''.$navactive.'"':'' ?>>

Comment: pls check your getbodyclass function and trace it or use my simple if statement to work.